# Rails Form Field for Selecting a State

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, states

I'm creating a Payment Form where users have to enter their state

In my users model, I have a `state` attribute

I have a `states` array as follows

```
states = %w(AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DC DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MA MI MN MO MS
MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VA VT WA WI WV WY)
```

I want to create a drop-down menu where users can select a state

I read the documentation, but am confused on how to implement it.

Would something like this work?

```
<%= select_tag(:state, options_for_select(states)) %>
```

The output should look like this

```
  AL
  AK
  ...
  WY
```

And you can select each of the options.

Comment: check this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not always a fan of just grabbing and installing gems, I have found the `Better State Select` gem to be handy in these scenarios. Mostly because I can't be bothered to keep arrays of states in multiple apps :)!

[Better State Select](https://github.com/yyyc514/better-states-select)

I ran your code just fine in one of my apps so I can't see an issue with what you have but wanted to offer the Better State Select gem suggestion simply because I've found it an easier way to manage things like states (and as we expand into Canadia, it already has their provinces, etc.).

Anyway, your code seems fine/workable to me as is!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, craig.kaminsky